# Using leaflet for R to make a pie chart with GIS data

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, r-leaflet

I am trying to make a point map that replaces the points with pie charts to make the information quicker to understand for the layman.

the alternative is:

"text": statistic
"text": statistic
"text": statistic
"text": statistic

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(plotly)
library(leaflet)
library(scales)
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet.minicharts)

ui <- dashboardPage( skin = "purple",
                     dashboardHeader(title = "Practice Map", titleWidth = 400),
                     dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
                     dashboardBody(
                       fluidPage(
                         useShinydashboard(),
                           fluidRow(
                             leafletOutput(outputId = "map")
                           )
  
                         )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet ({
 #extracting coordinates and adding to data
      map.tb <- map%>%
        st_coordinates() %>% 
        as_tibble() %>% 
        rename(lon = 1, lat = 2) %>% 
        bind_cols(map %>% st_drop_geometry())

      l <- leaflet(map) %>% 
        addTiles() %>% 
        addMinicharts(
          lng = map.tb$lon,
          lat = map.tb$lat,
          type = pie,
          chartdata = map.tb[,c(column1,column2,
                                column3,column4)],
          width = 60 * sqrt(map$colmun1) / sqrt(max(map$column1)), transitionTime = 0,
          fillColor = d3.schemeCategory10[1],
          colorPalette = d3.schemeCategory10
```

I keep getting this error.

`Error in match.arg: 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector`

does this mean I am missing an argument somewhere?

Let me know if any info is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Not really the way you are trying, but did you consider getting this done via QGIS? you can plot nodes on any map rather easily, and then instead of each point marker plot a pie chart with specified attributes.

you would just need to create a .txt file or similar with the following categories:

NODEx      NODEy       stat1        stat2      stat3      stat4

of course you can also enrich the file with node names or other infos, but this would work. Finally:
-Import the so-created file as delimited text,
-Right click the layer -> Poperties -> Diagram

customize the pie chart the way you want.
I know  I went a bit off track, but sometimes there are better tools for facing the same goal :)

Comment: I have never used qgis.  So you use it to make the maps then import those maps into R? We are combining this map with other charts and tables in an R shiny server

Comment: What format do you need the maps to be in? QGIS can quite comfortably create PNG, pdf, SVG. Probably more but I am also kind of a beginner

Comment: R-shiny interactive map